# Jetpack Compose theming at runtime

Tags: material-design, themes, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose and trying to experiment with theming.

I have a theme.kt file that looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun AppThemeProvider(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = CompositionLocalProvider(

    LocalColors     provides Colors(),
    LocalShapes     provides Shapes(),
    LocalTypography provides Typography(),
    content = content
)

object AppTheme {
    val colors: Colors @Composable get() = LocalColors.current
    val shapes: Shapes @Composable get() = LocalShapes.current
    val typography: Typography @Composable get() = LocalTypography.current    
}
```

And 3 classes for each provided values: Colors.kt, Shapes.kt and Typography.kt

This is my Colors class (The other 2 are basically the same):

```
data class Colors(
    val primary: Color = Color(0xFF00663f),
    val primaryVariant: Color = Color(0xFF007265),
    val onPrimary: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),

    val secondary: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    val secondaryVariant: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    val onSecondary: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),

    val background: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    val surface: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    val error: Color = Color(0xFFBF0013),

    val onBackground: Color = Color(0xFF3E3E3E),
    val onError: Color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),

)

val LocalColors = staticCompositionLocalOf { Colors() }

val colors: Colors
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalColors.current
```

Now, I have an API that I call during the splash screen that returns my theme as a JSON structure.

I'd like to use such response to build my 3 values classes to have a 'built-at-runtime' theme.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: of course is possible, you can get some inspiration from how the dark/light mode switch is handled at runtime, is pretty much the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can pass the `Colors` as a parameter to your `AppThemeProvider` composable and when the colors changes then the theme of your up will be updated.

Simple example:

```kotlin
var colors by remember { mutableStateOf(Colors()) }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
   colors = downloadColorsFromAPI()
}

AppThemeProvider(colors = colors) {
   App()
}
```

and your AppThemeProvider becomes:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppThemeProvider(
    colors: Colors = Colors(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = CompositionLocalProvider(

    LocalColors     provides colors,
    LocalShapes     provides Shapes(),
    LocalTypography provides Typography(),
    content = content
)
```